# split a number into whole number , decimal points and trailing digits

Tags: php, jquery

I have variables of bitcoin values all rounded to 8 decimal places. eg
`1.00645600`
I need a way in jQuery or php to get the whole number [1], The decimal values [006456], and trailing zeros [00]. I have already tried php substr but it messed up with the results since im dealing with variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and general solution in PHP without involving regular expressions (that is an option also):

```
$number = '1.00645600';

$flooredNumber = floor($number); // 1
$decimalPart = (string) (floatval($number) - $flooredNumber); // 0.006456
$decimals = str_replace('0.', '', $decimalPart); // 006456
$trailingZeros = str_replace(rtrim($number, '0'), '', $number); // 00
```

Comment: @ofumbi If it works like a charm, it would be nice to upvote apart form marking the post as the answer. Pure answer marking can be used if you haven't rights for upvoting (not your case), or it is a correct answer, but badly formulated and you want to make the author to improve it.

Comment: I would add that the code works for positive numbers only. It is totally OK for that very question, but somebody coming here by google could miss the point. +1

Answer (score 1):

> **substr**
>
> Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

If the numbers in your string are always in the same position you can use substr() to get the desired values:

```
$str = '1.00645600';
echo substr($str, 0, 1)."\r\n";
echo substr($str, 2, 2)."\r\n";
echo substr($str, 2, 6)."\r\n";
```

Output:

```
1
00
006456
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this way?

```
<?php    
    $i = '1.00645600';    
    echo rtrim(rtrim($i, '0'), '.');    
?>
```